# How to centeralize various z-indexed div classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

The page I have got is like this:[image: the image of my page.] .

I wanted to make it centralized but I couldnot do that.
The problems are:

1. I want to give black div full page.
2. I want to centralize other two divs without using left property in css.
3. While hovering the value of z should increase by any value so that the whole div can come up.

I learned about margin: 0 auto o auto; property that it centralizes the element with respect to page.
I want to get the same for yellow and green divs using margin property w.r.t. black divs.
Can I get these results using CSS or i will have to use Javascript etc?
My html code is here:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css"/>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="first">
            <center> <a href="http://www.google.com">The first link </a></center>
        </div>

        <div class="second">
            <center> <a href="http://www.fb.com"> The second link </a></center>
        </div>

        <div class="third">
            <center> <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"> The third link </a></center>
        </div>      
    </body>
<html>
```

My css document is:-

```
.first
{
    position: absolute;
    width:500px;
    color:#fff;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#000;
    z-index: 0;

    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

.second
{
    width:400px;
    position: absolute;
    height:200px;
    background-color: green;
    left:60px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin:50px auto 0 auto;

 }
 .third
 {
    position: absolute;
    width:300px;
    height: 200px;
    left:100px;
    background-color:yellow;
    z-index: 2;

        margin:100px auto 0 auto;
}

body div:first-child a:hover
{
    font-size:30px;
    color:yellow;
    z-index:5;
}
body  div +div a:hover
{
    font-size:40px;
    color:red;
    z-index: 5;
}
body div+div+div  a:hover
{
    font-size:50px;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:5;
}
```

I apologize for my English.And hope you will get my problems.

Comment: Why don't you nest those divs inside one another like http://jsfiddle.net/Z25Wm/

Comment: I donot know sir.Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: I have provided a fiddle along with my comment. Have a look at it. It does not use the 'left' property anywhere

Comment: Yes Sir.I need to use position property.

Comment: Why do you **not** want to use `left`? I don't foresee any problems with using it, if you know the right technique.

Comment: To use left we must have the value by which we have to move left.e.g. left:20px; which is not so easy to know.

Comment: @jahan Like I said, no problems if you know how to exploit it, or use it the right way. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**I still believe that using `left` is the best way to solve your problem — not sure why OP wants to avoid it.**

Here is the proof-of-concept fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/YqDL5/

Instead, use the following trick: set their position from the left by 50% of the container's/parent's width. That's half correct. However, we also need to take into account the width of the element itself, which means we have to offset it backwards by half of its own width.

Use this:

```
.second, .third {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

There are also some changes you have to make to your HTML code:

- I would suggest wrapping everything around a parent container that is relatively positioned, and instead of using margins to offset the second and third div from the top, use `top` instead.
- Remove `<center>`. Delegate layout to CSS, and this HTML tag has been deprecated long time ago.

Here is the revised HTML:

```
<section>
    <div class="first"><a href="http://www.google.com">The first link </a></div>
    <div class="second"><a href="http://www.fb.com"> The second link </a></div>
    <div class="third"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com"> The third link </a></div>     
</section>
```

Also, I suggest setting the first div to relative positioning, so it will not cause the parent element's height to collapse. Otherwise, you will have to set an explicit height since absolute positioning takes elements out of the flow, and the parent will not take it into account when calculating its own dimensions.

```
section {
    position: relative;
}
.first {
    width:100%;
    color:#fff;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#000;
}
.second, .third {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.second
{
    width:400px;
    position: absolute;
    height:200px;
    background-color: green;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
 }
 .third {
    position: absolute;
    width:300px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 100px;
    background-color:yellow;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

See fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/YqDL5/

Comment: In section you have given the value of position to relative and others to absolute.What does that mean?

Comment: I tell that all absolutely positioned elements within `<section>` should be relative to its parent. That's all. If you don't declare that, it will be relatively positioned against the closely positioned element, which is `<body>` (might be ok in your example, but not future proof when your layout changes).

Comment: I think here parent is section?

Comment: Sir you have used left property two times.IS using it once not sufficient..second, .third {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);  .second
{
    width:400px;
    position: absolute;
    height:200px;
    background-color: green;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
 }

Comment: No, the `left: 50%` was redundant later on... stylesheet is cascading so it will override anyway, no point declaring it twice. I just decided to combine the `left` and `transform` declarations for both the second and third div. Updated answer.